# No muestra imagen en vista detalle

Tags: python, django

Un poco de contexto, es para un sitio tipo blog en la que necesito mostrar en detalle el posteo (pagina), es decir todos los campos del modelo y además pasarle la imagen que corresponde a ese posteo (pagina).
Estas páginas esta asociadas al “autor” es decir nuestro user, de manera tal que cada usuario logueado pueda hacer un CRUD de su posteo (pagina).
A su vez está el modelo Imagenpagina la idea es que conectar esta imagen al id de cada pagina, de manera tal que al entrar al detalle de cada posteo cargue tmb su imagen.
Entonces la pagina esta asociada al autor(user) y a su vez la imagenpost a pagina.

[image: este es el error en concreto]

Aclaro que no puedo usar vistas basadas en clases o al menos evitarlas dentro de lo posible.

```
class Pagina(models.Model):
    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitulo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    autor= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cuerpo=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_posteo=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    actualizado=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo + " - " + str(self.autor)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pagina_detalle", args=(str(self.id)))


class Imagenpagina(models.Model):
    imgpost=models.ImageField(upload_to="post")
    pagina=models.ForeignKey(Pagina, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_posteo=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class Imagenpaginaform(forms.Form):
    imagenpagina=forms.ImageField(label="Imagen")
    
    class Meta:
        model=Pagina
        fields=["imagenpagina"]
        help_texts = {k:"" for k in fields}


def obtenerimagen(request):
    lista=Imagenpagina.objects.filter(pagina=request.pagina_id)
    if len(lista)!=0:
        imgpost=lista[0].imgpost.url
    else:
        imgpost=""
    return imgpost

def agregarimagen(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=Imagenpaginaform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            imgpost=Imagenpagina(user=request.user, imgpost=request.FILES["imgpost"])
            imgpostvieja=Imagenpagina.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            if len(imgpostvieja)>0:
                imgpostvieja[0].delete()
            imgpost.save()
            return render(request, "pagina_detalle.html", {"imgpost": obtenerimagen(request)})
        """else:
            return render(request, "agregar_Imagen.html", {"form": form, "usuario": request.user, "mensaje":"Error al agregar imagen"})"""

    else:
        form=Imagenpaginaform(instance=imgpost)
        return render(request, "agregar_Imagen.html", {"form":form, "imgpost": request.pagina})


def leerpaginas(request):
    paginas=Pagina.objects.all()
    contexto={"paginas":paginas}
    return render(request, "listapaginas_copia.html", contexto)

def paginadetalle(request, id=id):
    pagina=Pagina.objects.get(id=id)
    
    return render(request, "pagina_detalle.html", {"pagina":pagina, "imgpost":obtenerimagen(request)})

path('paginadetalle/<id>', views.paginadetalle, name="paginadetalle"),
path('leerpaginas/', views.leerpaginas, name="leerpaginas"),
```

## {{pagina.titulo}}

```
<p>{{pagina.subtitulo}}</p>
<p>{{pagina.autor}}</p>
<p>{{pagina.fecha_posteo}}</p>
```

{{pagina.cuerpo|safe}}

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'leerpaginas' %}">Volver</a>


{% if user.id == pagina.autor.id %}
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'editarpagina' pagina.id %}">Editar</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'pagina_borrar' pagina.id %}">Borrar</a>

{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: Las relación que estas haciendo en ningún momento se está haciendo la asoción con el objeto request. más bien sería algo como lo siguiente: pagina_id = request.user.autor.last().pagina.last().id y ese ya lo usas con tu método  obtenerimagen

Comment: En si el flujo a seguir sería así: request -> user -> Pagina ->Imagenpagina -> pagina_id

Comment: Hola Leyco gracias por tu respuesta pero no estaría entendiendo, porque incluir al user, solo necesito relacionar la pgina con la imagen

Comment: Al user lo tengo para decir "esta pagina, es de este usuario" y ahora necesito decir "esta imagen, corresponde a esta pagina" independiemnte del autor de esa manera una persona que no esta logueada puede ver el posteo con la imagen

Comment: Es tener una lista de imagenes y de esa lista filtrar las imagenes segun su pag id

Comment: Quizás se puede plantear la búsqueda desde otro lugar y yo de tanto darle vueltas ya estoy cegado

Comment: En si lo que sucede es que estás usando el objeto request, pero has un print(dir(requets)) para que veas los valores que tiene, y como tal no tiene los valores de la imagen, por eso te muestra ese error. Haz la prueba y pon una captura o el código de lo que te muestra, por favor.